# What word means "diseñar" and "desarrollar"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

As the title says, what word includes both "diseñar" and "desarrollar" meanings? This is in the context of software development.

Comment: I would think on "crear"

Comment: I agree with @fedorqui, if you want to group the two words together you need to go for some more general words, like _crear_ or _construir un sitio web_, as the construction of a web site (or any other piece of software) imply a lot of tasks including the design and development of the site.

Comment: You are probably asking for a non-existent word because it join two concepts that in reality would never come together, like "_a word that means both a fruit and the dish on which it is served_." Is there a word in _any_ language that brings together "diseño" and "desarrollo"?

Comment: If you look both words in any dictionary you will see that they are **not synonyms** in any context. So the answer is **There is no word meaning the same as two other words that are not synonyms of each other**

Comment: @DGaleano Regardless of what these words may "technically" mean according to the dictionary, I would say that `Diseñar` does not imply `Desarrollar` but that **in the software industry** `Desarrollar` **may or may not** imply the inception and design stages. Thus, they may not be synonyms, but there is ambiguity in the scope of `Desarrollar` for this specific domain. The OP could _technically_ use `Desarrollar` and imply both software stages (that would be the word he is looking for), but it would be impossible to know for sure if he was including the `diseño` or not.

Comment: @Diego if a person **knows** the software industry then he knows what he is talking about and knows these two words refer to two different stages of the process. If the person **does not know** the software industry then for him these words also mean different things (as you can see in any dictionary). So in both cases they are not synonyms nor can they be used to talk about the same thing and then there is no single word that can be synonym to both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None. And it may be not surprising. Although in other contexts these words may be synonyms, in software we specialized their meanings, in order to describe phases of software development (or software engineering). What is worse, Spanish had to catch up with terms in a different language as technologies an methodologies developed. I don't think the Spanish terms lack a depth of meaning that terms may have in different languages. I just think these terms got "*overloaded*" when incorporated to the software industry.

`Diseñar` would imply that you were involved in the early stages of the project/application, lets say, the *Análisis de requerimientos*, *Especificación*, *Diseño de la arquitectura o modelo* and the like.

`Desarrollar` implies *Programación* or the *coding* itself. In the context of software engineering it will probably imply testing and debugging.

You want to convey the (full life cycle of the) development of software for a given project (at least until the development phase, according to your question. I don't know if Q&A is intended as well to be on the scope of the meaning of the word you are looking for...).

So unfortunately, *desarrollo* (development) is (or has become) ambiguous enough to carry both the meaning of just a specific step of the development cycle (coding) and the boarder meaning that it has in different context (meaning realization, fulfillment or "bring to existence" of an idea, project, task, ...) thus meaning "whole software life cycle development".

If you were to describe on your (Spanish) resume that you took part both on the coding and the analysis-design of an application you will need to be explicit about it, since no single word covers both "*Diseño y desarrollo*" without ambiguity in software.

Comment: This also applies to English, the Software Development Life Cycle includes both design (diseño) and development (desarrollo). If the question was asked for a word that means both design and development in English, you would face the same predicament. So, while Spanish had to catch up with some terms, that might not be the case for these two. A lot of the terms of software development have been borrowed from existing industries, mainly the construction industry. I do agree that there is "none" without more explanation from OP to what he is trying to convey and an equivalent English word.

Comment: Great answer that goes beyond the topic to talk about this very interesting topic of _Spanish had to catch up with terms in a different language as technologies an methodologies developed_. The language is clearly behind and its attempts to use native words are normally overwhelmingly surpassed by the _Spanishation_ of the English word. Browsing through [questions with the tag _informática_](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inform%C3%A1tica) reveals multiple cases.